# Add custom button to the selection's tooltip in Outlook

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js

I've created my own add-in for Outlook with VueJS.
In order to communicate with my plugin I need to add custom button to the tooltip, when user selects something in an email reply.
Is there any way to do it with manifest file? Or... ?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently adding custom button to tooltip is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. 
So, in this case, is there is event trigger for text selection?
Sure, I can run setInterval and check it, but I'm pretty sure this is the worst way ;)

Comment: Hi, currently there is no event trigger for text selection. But we have an api for setting selected data: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#setselecteddataasync-data--options--callback-